# How many tiling?

Tags: tiling, tessellations

Recently, I study tiling of the plane with regular polygon which is edge-to edge.

If we restrict to the two triangles and two hexagons, then we can slide rows of tiles so that in adjacent rows,
we either match triangle edges to triangle edges or we match triangle edges to hexagon edges, this implies that there exist infinity of
distinct tilings by two triangles and two hexagons.

I would like to know the number of distinct tiling if type of every vertex is $3.6.3.6$?

Is it true that there is only one tiling such that type of every vertex is $3.6.3.6$?

Comment: When you say "restrict to two triangles and two hexagons", do you mean that two triangles and two hexagons meet at every vertex?

Comment: @Karl, yes. In every vertex, we have  two triangles and two hexagons.

Comment: And "$3^2 . 6^2$" means what?

Comment: @JBL, this means that type of tiles in a vertex is finite  sequence triangle, triangle, hexagon and hexagon.Note that tiling is edge-to-edge and every tile is regular polygon.

Comment: @JBL, Sorry, the type of tiling can not be $3^2.6^2$.

Comment: But, it can be $3.6.3.6$

Comment: The fact that there is only one 3.6.3.6 tiling is one of those things that writing down a formal proof can only obscure what becomes obvious once you start drawing it: as soon as you put down the first shape, the entire thing is forced to propagate outwards in a unique way.